# Error initializing graphdriver: invalid argument

Tags: docker

I have an AWS EC2 instance with EBS mounted as `/docker`:

> ```
> root@ip-10-0-0-235:~# lsblk /dev/xvdc1 
> NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
> xvdc1 202:33   0  100G  0 part /docker
> ```

Then I have `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with:

```
{
  "graph": "/docker/"
}
```

After Docker version was updated - I had to change `graph` to `data-root` as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/enterprise/17.06/#17062-ee-4-2017-10-12):

```
{
  "data-root": "/docker/"
}
```

But after that change - I faced with another error:

```
Nov 22 09:15:31 ip-10-0-0-235 dockerd[5671]: time="2017-11-22T09:15:31.168591095Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 5679"
Nov 22 09:15:32 ip-10-0-0-235 dockerd[5671]: time="2017-11-22T09:15:32.170033835Z" level=warning msg="failed to rename /docker/tmp for background deletion: %!s(<nil>). Deleting synchronously"
Nov 22 09:15:32 ip-10-0-0-235 dockerd[5671]: time="2017-11-22T09:15:32.172631277Z" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver aufs failed: invalid argument"
Nov 22 09:15:32 ip-10-0-0-235 dockerd[5671]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: invalid argument
```

What's the correct way now to mount it?

Docker 17.05.0-ce, running on Ubuntu 16.04.3.

P.S. During writing this Q - found weird mounted partition:

> ```
> root@ip-10-0-0-235:~# mount | grep xvd
> /dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
> /dev/xvda1 on /docker/aufs type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
> /dev/xvdb1 on /jenkins type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
> /dev/xvdc1 on /docker type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
> ```

`/dev/xvda1 on /docker/aufs` and `/dev/xvdc1 on /docker`. That doesn't looks correct...